# SignalR: Empty Hub Script file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-client

I'm trying to use SignalR for the real time notifications, but I have a problem.

The generated script hub file is empty. I have the error at the client:

> jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js:9 Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs.
> Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. .

When debugging the calls I saw that, the assembly of the script content is created well (image 1, 2).

But when I try to convert it to binary `(var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))` in the `ResponseExtensions class (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting)` the result is empty (image 3).

In the attached screenshots you can see the content and post conversion.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKBsX.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN4ju.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8QSR.png)

Does anyone know what the problem will be?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I've already found the problem. The problem comes from the gzip compression we use in the application.